# Reveal the password in the blank text

Tags: cipher, password, steganography

To get more evidence, a police is trying to hack a criminal's computer.
He finds a suspicious transaction file, but it is protected by a password.
Than he find a text file which he thinks contain the needed password.

He says to himself : "*What a fool to save the password here*"

But, when he open the text file it is blank.

Help the police to reveal the hidden password.

---

---

Note :
 
I can not upload the blank text file,
So, please click edit question, and check the code between two dashes.

Comment: -1; IMO it's not good for the solver to have to hack the question-message (by clicking on "edit") in order to get to a vital part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

> [HelloBOSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP2s-GqC7Jw)

because

> The characters in the text file have the decimal ASCII values 32 (space) and 9 (h-tab) (not counting line breaks):
>
> ```
> 32 9 32 32 9 32 32 32
> 32 9 9 32 32 9 32 9
> 32 9 9 32 9 9 32 32
> 32 9 9 32 9 9 32 32
> 32 9 9 32 9 9 9 9
> 32 9 32 32 32 32 9 32
> 32 9 32 32 9 9 9 9
> 32 9 32 9 32 32 9 9
> 32 9 32 9 32 32 9 9
> ```
>
> Now, for each line, convert 32 to 0 and 9 to 1:
>
> ```
> 01001000
> 01100101
> 01101100
> 01101100
> 01101111
> 01000010
> 01001111
> 01010011
> 01010011
> ```
>
> Then convert the bytes to ASCII:
>
> ```
> HelloBOSS
> ```

Comment: 25 reputation for you, for answering very fast and easy to understand.

Comment: should Be helloBOSS

Comment: @numberknot Nice catch, no idea how I managed to miss the second 'S'. I edited the answer now. I think the capitalized 'H' is correct, though.